Apache Solr query with a 120 seconds elapsed time
our application performs searches against different cores present within a Solr Cloud architecture hosted on three servers. On some rare occasions we log some queries with an elapsed time of 120 seconds but with a QTime of a few milliseconds. On such occasions we have tracked this type of information:
DEBUG wire:87 - http-outgoing-1920 << "[read] I/O error: Read timed out"
...
DEBUG DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:79 - http-outgoing-1920: Close connection  
DEBUG DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:96 - http-outgoing-1920: Shutdown connection
DEBUG MainClientExec:129 - Connection discarded 
DEBUG SolrHttpRequestRetryHandler:115 - Do not retry, non retriable class java.net.SocketTimeoutException

What causes this problem and how can it be eliminated?
Thanks
